# How to implement SetFullscreenstate properly?

Tags: directx, dxgi

I know that DX12 does not support FSE anymore. But I still see many DX11 games with 3 options: Windowed, Borderless Fullscreen, and Fullscreen. I'm pretty sure the last one is implemented as IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState, but after a few days of trying, I couldn't come up with a robust implementation without debug layer errors or flashes (the screen sometimes flashes a previous frame when transitioning with SetFullScreenState). I want to implement SetFullscreenstate because for some reason it still runs better than a borderless window.
I couldn't find any other example online either. How do you implement this technique?

Comment: FSE has become "Fullscreen optimizations" which is essentially the same thing. I have no problems calling `IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState`. It should work. Post the errors

Comment: Well I was getting `IDXGISwapChain::Present: The application has not called ResizeBuffers or re-created the SwapChain after a fullscreen or windowed transition` but I fixed that. Because the fullscreen state clears after alt tab, I re-apply fullscreen state when the window is reactivated. Now I'm running into a weird issue where alt-tabbing back into a fullscreen window shows a flicker of a past frame; what's the best way to fix that?

Comment: I don't resize/recreate the swapchain and just make sure not to present when not in FSE, DWM just clips the top left corner. Maybe the flicker is the new created Backbuffer that hasn't been rendered to, being shown. If its not a big deal, maybe just ignore it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does your system handle fullscreen <-> windowed transitions via SetFullscreenState correctly? If so, could you explain how you handle the  event when fullscreen state gets cleared when you alt-tab out of the fullscreen application? That is where the source of the flickering and alt-tab menu glitches are for me.

Comment: Please post some reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/b5f92e2251ee83db4d4c795b3cba5d470c52eaf8/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp#L685) does what you are trying to do (only when `m_tearingSupport` is false). My "solution" is to pause presenting/rendering when the user alt-tabs out i.e. not support running in windowed mode.

Comment: You may want to read [this blog series](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/).